# Write a Python function to get the excel files from the input folder and also check whether it is in csv format or xlsx format

Tags: python

Python function to get the excel files from the input folder and also check whether it is in csv format or xlsx format

```
def import_files(input_file_path):
    for filename in os.listdir(input_file_path):
        if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
            excel_files=pd.read_excel(input_file_path+'//'+filename,encoding='utf-8',dtype=str)
            print("Read Excel File Name: "+filename)
            print("Displaying Sample Record:")
            print(excel_files.iloc[1])
        else:
            print("File Format Not Supported: "+filename)
    return excel_files
```

Comment: Hello @bhaskar welcome to stackoverflow. In order to make your answer easier to understand and helpful to other people in the future, could you please add some details of what you have tried or what errors are you getting? Also please refer to [how to ask questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: Hello @bahaskar, could you add a question to your question? We have understood the problem you try to solve but we fail to understand what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is to fetch files and check if its excel or csv files then below is the code:

```
xlfile=[]
def import_files(input_file_path): 
    for f in os.listdir(input_file_path):
        if f.endswith('.xlsx'):
            xlfile.append(f)
        if f.endswith('.csv'):
            print("File Format Not Supported: ",f)
    return xlfile

excelfiles=import_files(input_file_path)    
print(excelfiles)
```

Comment: thanks @Python_Bang but i want to return it as well if it is a normal excel file

Comment: @bhaskargethe I have modified it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution:

```
import glob

xlsx_files = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
csv_files = glob.glob('*.csv')
other_files = [filename for filename in glob.glob('*') if not (filename in xlsx_files or filename in csv_files)]
```

If you didn't like how `other_files` was defined, you can use regex to get the same output because `glob.glob` accepts regex expressions, but I am not an expert in regex.